# How to find a matrix for linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

$T: \mathbb R^2[x] \to \mathbb R^2[x]$ is given with the regulation: $(Tp)(x) = (xp(x))'$

If $q(x) = 1 - x + x^2$, what is T*(q)?

I don't understand what the left side of the regulation means and how to get a matrix from the regulation, also I apologize for the poor formatting.

Edit: The asterisk sign should be above T in the question with q, as in adjugate matrix.

Comment: Why do you need to construct a matrix?  Just multiply by $x$ and take the derivative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

The transformation $T$ is acting on the polynomial $p(x)$ to give the output as the derivative of $xp(x)$. For example, $T(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)=2x$ and so on.

To get the matrix you should determine the behavior of the transformation $T$ on a basis like $\{1,x,x^2\}$.

Comment: Well it changes 1 to 1, x to 2x and x^2 to 3x^2 but I dont know how that helps me get the matrix T

Comment: @KristjanGajšek if you want to compute $T(q(x))=T(1-x+x^2)$, then as Bye-World pointed in the comments, you don't need the matrix. You can simply use linearity to get $T(1-x+x^2)=T(1)-T(x)+T(x^2)=1-2x+3x^2$ and you are done.

Comment: @KristjanGajšek but if you insist on a matrix then think of $x$ as the vector $(0,1,0)$. This gives $T((0,1,0))=(0,2,0)$, likewise think of other polynomials and you can get the matrix based on that.

Comment: Okay, I get it now, thank you very much!